# Spanning Table on Two Pages in IEEE Journal Transaction?

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I am trying to put a table in IEEE transaction paper which is extremely long and will span on two pages. But I am unable to do it using current packages that I am using: Any suggestions would be extremely helpful.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[t!]
        \centering
        \caption{Comparison of SDP and BFM-SOCP based relaxation for multi-phase Active DNNs for $R_{gnd}=1\Omega$}
        \scriptsize
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
        \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\textbf{OF:1 Slack Bus Power (kVA)}}\\ \hline
            \multirow{6}{*}{\textbf{LMs}}&\multicolumn{5}{c||}{\textit{Y-connected End-Users}}&\multicolumn{5}{c||}{\textit{$\Delta$-connected End-Users}}&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textit{Y-$\Delta$ connected End-Users}}\\ \cline{2-16}
            &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{SDP}}&\multicolumn{3}{c||}{\textbf{BFM-SOCP}}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{SDP}}&\multicolumn{3}{c||}{\textbf{BFM-SOCP}}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{SDP}}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{BFM-SOCP}}\\ \cline{2-16}
            &{\thead{\textit{EVR} \\ $|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1|$\\ $\times 10^{-5}$}}&{\thead{\textit{Obj.}\\\textit{Value}}}&\multicolumn{3}{c||}{\textit{\% Optimality Gap}}&{\thead{\textit{EVR} \\ $|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1|$\\ $\times 10^{-5}$}}&{\thead{\textit{Obj.}\\\textit{Value}}}&\multicolumn{3}{c||}{\textit{\% Optimality Gap}}&{\thead{\textit{EVR} \\ $|\lambda_2|/|\lambda_1|$\\ $\times 10^{-5}$}}&{\thead{\textit{Obj.}\\\textit{Value}}}&\multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textit{\% Optimality Gap}} \\ \hline       
            \multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\textbf{MicroGrid: Lightly Unbalanced DN}}\\ \hline
            \textbf{LM:1}&0.32&2826.2&0.00&0.00 &0.00   &   2.86    &   2810.1  &   0.57    &   0.57    &   0.58    &   1.12    &   2829.5  &   0.16    &   0.16    &   0.16\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:2}&0.15&2917.4&\textbf{4.33}&\textbf{12.2}   &\textit{0.10}  &   0.72    &   2917.6  &   \textbf{4.34}   &   \textbf{12.2}   &   \textit{0.09}   &   1.65    &   2906.2  &   \textbf{4.33}   &   \textbf{11.8}   &   \textit{0.50}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:3}&0.16&3019.7&0.04&0.04 &0.04   &   1.18    &   3027.2  &   0.21    &   0.21    &   0.20    &   0.17    &   3021.8  &   0.06    &   0.06    &   0.06\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:4}&0.30&2881.0&0.04&0.04 &0.39   &   0.05    &   2882.7  &   0.10    &   0.10    &   0.45    &   \textbf{55.2}   &   3131.1  &   0.45    &   0.09    &   1.34\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:5}&0.15&2927.8&0.02&0.02 &0.01   &   2.26    &   2940.4  &   0.41    &   0.41    &   0.42    &   0.17    &   2928.8  &   0.01    &   0.01    &   0.00\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:6}&0.28&2918.5&0.03&0.03 &0.15   &   0.15    &   2920.9  &   0.05    &   0.05    &   0.23    &   0.40    &   2943.6  &   0.01    &   0.03    &   0.31\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:7}&0.04&2943.8&0.01&0.01 &0.10   &   0.16    &   2942.9  &   0.02    &   0.02    &   0.07    &   1.53    &   2944.2  &   0.03    &   0.03    &   0.06\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:8}&1.27&2953.6&0.24&0.24 &0.24   &   0.11    &   2946.0  &   0.02    &   0.02    &   0.02    &   0.28    &   2944.7  &   0.09    &   0.09    &   0.09\\\hline

            \multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\textbf{IT-37: Moderately Unbalanced DN}}\\
            \textbf{LM:1}&0.34  &97.7 &0.15&0.15&   0.15&   0.11&   98.0    &   0.01    &   0.01    &   0.01    &   0.47    &   97.4    &   0.03    &   0.03    &   0.03\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:2}&1.34  &100.7&\textbf{6.13}&\textbf{13.7}& \textit{0.23}&  0.28&   100.7   &   \textbf{6.02}   &   \textbf{13.8}   &   \textit{0.21}   &   0.93    &   100.6   &   \textbf{6.62}   &   \textbf{13.52}  &   \textit{0.27}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:3}&0.84  &104.0&0.14&0.14&   0.14&   0.51&   103.9   &   0.13    &   0.13    &   0.13    &   0.48    &   104.2   &   0.30    &   0.30    &   0.30\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:4}&1.96  &98.4 &0.66&0.66&   0.88&   1.87&   112.9   &   \textit{0.51}   &   \textit{0.18}   &   \textbf{1.67}   &   \textbf{110}    &   122.3   &   1.53    &   3.28    &   4.79\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:5}&0.56  &101.0&0.18&0.18&   0.17&   0.46&   101.2   &   0.00    &   0.00    &   0.01    &   0.53    &   101.0   &   0.14    &   0.14    &   0.13\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:6}&1.47  &100.3&0.33&0.33&   0.35&   0.36&   102.9   &   0.23    &   0.27    &   0.45    &   0.93    &   102.8   &   0.51    &   0.33    &   0.01\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:7}&0.44  &101.1&0.34&0.34&   0.37&   0.18&   101.5   &   0.12    &   0.12    &   0.05    &   0.28    &   101.4   &   0.04    &   0.03    &   0.07\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:8}&0.66  &101.6&0.25&0.25&   0.25&   0.15&   101.8   &   0.04    &   0.04    &   0.04    &   0.34    &   101.8   &   0.14    &   0.14    &   0.14\\\hline

            \multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\textbf{Cigre: Highly Unbalanced DN}}\\
            \textbf{LM:1}&1.09&146.4&0.07&0.07& 0.07&   1.58&   146.7   &   0.04    &   0.04    &   0.04    &   0.93    &   146.6   &   0.03    &   0.03    &   0.03\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:2}&1.02&153.8&\textbf{10.8}&\textbf{21.1}&   \textit{0.16}&  1.39&   153.9   &   \textbf{9.14}   &   \textbf{20.9}   &   \textit{0.18}   &   0.90    &   153.8   &   \textbf{10.12}  &   \textbf{20.9}   &\textit{0.19}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:3}&0.72&162.7&0.00&0.00& 0.00&   0.92&   162.8   &   0.02    &   0.02    &   0.02    &   1.27    &   162.8   &   0.05    &   0.05    &   0.05\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:4}&\textbf{13.1}&150.0&0.01&7.63&    8.68&   \textbf{1680}&  194.3   &   0.84    &   29.9    &   31.9    &   \textbf{120}    &   160.7   &   1.04    &   11.8    &   13.1\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:5}&0.77&154.8&0.01&0.01& 0.02&   0.78&   155.1   &   0.00    &   0.00    &   0.05    &   1.25    &   154.9   &   0.03    &   0.03    &   0.00\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:6}&7.03&154.0&0.03&0.10& 0.59&   \textbf{63.3}&  167.5   &   1.65    &   0.81    &   2.89    &   4.44    &   156.4   &   1.02    &   0.59    &   0.77\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:7}&3.11&156.1&0.00&0.02& 0.23&   1.93&   157.1   &   \textbf{1.19}   &   \textbf{1.04}   &   \textit{0.35}   &   2.21    &   156.5   &   0.02    &   0.03    &   0.24\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:8}&0.82&156.3&0.01&0.01& 0.01&   1.52&   156.5   &   0.02    &   0.02    &   0.02    &   1.18    &   156.4   &   0.03    &   0.03    &   0.03\\\hline

            \multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\textbf{IEEE-13: Highly Unbalanced DN}}\\
            \textbf{LM:1}&0.66&3620.4&0.17&0.17 &0.17   &   3.17&   3623.5  &   0.75    &   0.75    &   0.76    &   1.17    &   3611.7  &   0.42    &   0.42    &   0.43\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:2}&0.54&3810.3&\textbf{12.7}&\textbf{21.7}   &\textit{0.34}  &   4.91&   3796.8  &   \textbf{10.0}   &   \textbf{19.9}   &   \textit{0.46}   &   1.69    &   3808.2  &   \textbf{13.3}   &   \textbf{22.1}   &   \textit{0.40}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:3}&1.50&4033.6&0.40&0.40 &0.40   &   0.74&   3991.5  &   0.06    &   0.06    &   0.06    &   2.21    &   4062.8  &   0.23    &   0.23    &   0.23\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:4}&3.26&3639.6&\textbf{2.45}&\textbf{8.02}   &\textit{0.79}  &   \textbf{5870}&  8535.5  &   9.65    &   24.5    &   5.34    &   2.79    &   3932.1  &   \textbf{2.48}   &   \textbf{4.54}   &   \textit{0.56}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:5}&1.36&3825.8&0.39&0.30 &0.39   &   0.53&   3830.1  &   0.05    &   0.05    &   0.06    &   2.02    &   3877.3  &   0.84    &   0.94    &   0.86\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:6}&1.14&3777.7&0.10&0.10 &0.61   &   \textbf{170}    &   1265.9  &   3.86    &   5.00    &   0.05    &   3.78    &   3799.0  &   \textbf{2.24}   &   \textbf{3.01}   &   \textit{0.66}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:7}&1.34&3852.9&0.05&0.66 &0.32   &   0.40&   3868.5  &   0.14    &   0.18    &   0.24    &   1.15    &   3859.5  &   0.18    &   0.50    &   0.02\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:8}&4.89&3891.4&0.86&0.86 &0.87   &   0.14&   3865.0  &   0.01    &   0.01    &   0.01    &   3.84    &   3878.8  &   0.47    &   0.47    &   0.47\\\hline

                        \multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\textbf{IEEE-13: Highly Unbalanced DN}}\\
            \textbf{LM:1}&0.66&3620.4&0.17&0.17 &0.17   &   3.17&   3623.5  &   0.75    &   0.75    &   0.76    &   1.17    &   3611.7  &   0.42    &   0.42    &   0.43\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:2}&0.54&3810.3&\textbf{12.7}&\textbf{21.7}   &\textit{0.34}  &   4.91&   3796.8  &   \textbf{10.0}   &   \textbf{19.9}   &   \textit{0.46}   &   1.69    &   3808.2  &   \textbf{13.3}   &   \textbf{22.1}   &   \textit{0.40}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:3}&1.50&4033.6&0.40&0.40 &0.40   &   0.74&   3991.5  &   0.06    &   0.06    &   0.06    &   2.21    &   4062.8  &   0.23    &   0.23    &   0.23\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:4}&3.26&3639.6&\textbf{2.45}&\textbf{8.02}   &\textit{0.79}  &   \textbf{5870}&  8535.5  &   9.65    &   24.5    &   5.34    &   2.79    &   3932.1  &   \textbf{2.48}   &   \textbf{4.54}   &   \textit{0.56}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:5}&1.36&3825.8&0.39&0.30 &0.39   &   0.53&   3830.1  &   0.05    &   0.05    &   0.06    &   2.02    &   3877.3  &   0.84    &   0.94    &   0.86\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:6}&1.14&3777.7&0.10&0.10 &0.61   &   \textbf{170}    &   1265.9  &   3.86    &   5.00    &   0.05    &   3.78    &   3799.0  &   \textbf{2.24}   &   \textbf{3.01}   &   \textit{0.66}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:7}&1.34&3852.9&0.05&0.66 &0.32   &   0.40&   3868.5  &   0.14    &   0.18    &   0.24    &   1.15    &   3859.5  &   0.18    &   0.50    &   0.02\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:8}&4.89&3891.4&0.86&0.86 &0.87   &   0.14&   3865.0  &   0.01    &   0.01    &   0.01    &   3.84    &   3878.8  &   0.47    &   0.47    &   0.47\\\hline

                        \multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\textbf{IEEE-13: Highly Unbalanced DN}}\\
            \textbf{LM:1}&0.66&3620.4&0.17&0.17 &0.17   &   3.17&   3623.5  &   0.75    &   0.75    &   0.76    &   1.17    &   3611.7  &   0.42    &   0.42    &   0.43\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:2}&0.54&3810.3&\textbf{12.7}&\textbf{21.7}   &\textit{0.34}  &   4.91&   3796.8  &   \textbf{10.0}   &   \textbf{19.9}   &   \textit{0.46}   &   1.69    &   3808.2  &   \textbf{13.3}   &   \textbf{22.1}   &   \textit{0.40}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:3}&1.50&4033.6&0.40&0.40 &0.40   &   0.74&   3991.5  &   0.06    &   0.06    &   0.06    &   2.21    &   4062.8  &   0.23    &   0.23    &   0.23\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:4}&3.26&3639.6&\textbf{2.45}&\textbf{8.02}   &\textit{0.79}  &   \textbf{5870}&  8535.5  &   9.65    &   24.5    &   5.34    &   2.79    &   3932.1  &   \textbf{2.48}   &   \textbf{4.54}   &   \textit{0.56}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:5}&1.36&3825.8&0.39&0.30 &0.39   &   0.53&   3830.1  &   0.05    &   0.05    &   0.06    &   2.02    &   3877.3  &   0.84    &   0.94    &   0.86\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:6}&1.14&3777.7&0.10&0.10 &0.61   &   \textbf{170}    &   1265.9  &   3.86    &   5.00    &   0.05    &   3.78    &   3799.0  &   \textbf{2.24}   &   \textbf{3.01}   &   \textit{0.66}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:7}&1.34&3852.9&0.05&0.66 &0.32   &   0.40&   3868.5  &   0.14    &   0.18    &   0.24    &   1.15    &   3859.5  &   0.18    &   0.50    &   0.02\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:8}&4.89&3891.4&0.86&0.86 &0.87   &   0.14&   3865.0  &   0.01    &   0.01    &   0.01    &   3.84    &   3878.8  &   0.47    &   0.47    &   0.47\\\hline

                        \multicolumn{16}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!50}\textbf{IEEE-13: Highly Unbalanced DN}}\\
            \textbf{LM:1}&0.66&3620.4&0.17&0.17 &0.17   &   3.17&   3623.5  &   0.75    &   0.75    &   0.76    &   1.17    &   3611.7  &   0.42    &   0.42    &   0.43\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:2}&0.54&3810.3&\textbf{12.7}&\textbf{21.7}   &\textit{0.34}  &   4.91&   3796.8  &   \textbf{10.0}   &   \textbf{19.9}   &   \textit{0.46}   &   1.69    &   3808.2  &   \textbf{13.3}   &   \textbf{22.1}   &   \textit{0.40}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:3}&1.50&4033.6&0.40&0.40 &0.40   &   0.74&   3991.5  &   0.06    &   0.06    &   0.06    &   2.21    &   4062.8  &   0.23    &   0.23    &   0.23\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:4}&3.26&3639.6&\textbf{2.45}&\textbf{8.02}   &\textit{0.79}  &   \textbf{5870}&  8535.5  &   9.65    &   24.5    &   5.34    &   2.79    &   3932.1  &   \textbf{2.48}   &   \textbf{4.54}   &   \textit{0.56}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:5}&1.36&3825.8&0.39&0.30 &0.39   &   0.53&   3830.1  &   0.05    &   0.05    &   0.06    &   2.02    &   3877.3  &   0.84    &   0.94    &   0.86\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:6}&1.14&3777.7&0.10&0.10 &0.61   &   \textbf{170}    &   1265.9  &   3.86    &   5.00    &   0.05    &   3.78    &   3799.0  &   \textbf{2.24}   &   \textbf{3.01}   &   \textit{0.66}\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:7}&1.34&3852.9&0.05&0.66 &0.32   &   0.40&   3868.5  &   0.14    &   0.18    &   0.24    &   1.15    &   3859.5  &   0.18    &   0.50    &   0.02\\\hline
            \textbf{LM:8}&4.89&3891.4&0.86&0.86 &0.87   &   0.14&   3865.0  &   0.01    &   0.01    &   0.01    &   3.84    &   3878.8  &   0.47    &   0.47    &   0.47\\\hline

        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tablenotes}\scriptsize
            \centering 
            \item LM: Load Model \hspace{0.2em} EVR: Eigen Value Ratio  \hspace{0.2em} \hspace{0.2em} IT: Italian \hspace{0.2em} SDP: Semi-Definite Programming \hspace{0.2em} BFM-SOCP: Branch Flow Relaxation-Second Order Cone Programming
        \end{tablenotes}
        \label{Table_2}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be interested in using the `longtable` package.

Comment: I have already tried it but it cannot be used in a two column mode.

Comment: Use `\onecolumn` before `longtable` and `twocolumn` after `longtable`  ...